# storm - handling exceptions in bolt.execute

Tags: cassandra, apache-storm

Im using [storm](https://storm.apache.org/) to process a stream wherein one of the bolts is writing to **cassandra**. The cassandra `session.execute()` command can throw an exception and I'm wondering about trapping this to 'fail' the tuple so it gets retried.

The docs for **IRichBolt** don't [show](https://storm.apache.org/apidocs/backtype/storm/task/IBolt.html#execute(backtype.storm.tuple.Tuple)) it throwing anything so I'm wondering how the exception cases are being handled.

Primary question: should I wrap the cassandra call in a try/catch or will storm manage this case for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multipart answer:

1) Definitely surround your code with a try-catch block.

2) How to handle failure depends on the Storm topology and kind of failure:

If the exception indicates that an immediate retry might work, then you could loop some small, finite number of times until the attempt does work or you run out of tries.

If the tuple that you're executing is the tuple that was emitted by the spout then your bolt can fail the tuple.  That will force a retry by Storm (that is to say that the fail() method on the spout will be called and you can code the retry)

If there's already been at least one side effect as a result of processing this tuple and you don't want to repeat that side effect as a result of retrying the tuple, then you need to get a little more creative.  Your Cassandra bolt can emit the failed tuple onto a failed-tuple stream where it can be persisted somewhere (HBase, file system, Kafka) until you're ready to try again.  To try again you can add another Spout to your topology that reads from that store of failed tuples and emits them on a stream back to the Cassandra bolt for the retry.  That gives you a way to continuously loop your retries with an extended time between retries.  If along with the failed tuple you also persist/log the Cassandra exception, you can browse/monitor the log to see if there are any issues your admin should know.

Comment: How about in 'prepare' - how to fail the call so the topology tries again?

Comment: @ethrbunny  The prepare() method is called only once so that the bolt can configure and initialize itself.  There is no tuple passed in to prepare().  As for other errors, like a connection error to Cassandra in the prepare(), you should catch the exception (so yes - surround your logic with a try-catch) and throw a RuntimeException.  Storm will reattempt to start the task (with another call to prepare()) and you hope the connection attempt work the second or third time around.